# How to call a method of any php class via linux server

Tags: php, linux, scheduling

I am new to linux. I have a class named Schedule having one methos DoAction() in php. I want my linux server to call the method DoAction() after some intervals of 15 minutes, 1hour, 6 hours, each week and each month. Please give me some ideas to achieve this goal. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron job to execute a PHP program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905605/cron-job-to-execute-a-php-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has a system-wide shceduler called `cron`. It is very probably already installed.

More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks. My application is something different. I have a database table integration having some integration records. some records will execute in each 30 minutes some each 1 hour, etc. DoAction() function does different task according to settings saved in integration record. Now if 10 records are set to run each 15 minutes, I want to call DoAction() at a time for all integration records. I have a php page which is set using crone job for each 15 minutes. But in this case DoAction is calling one by one for 10 records As I am calling DoAction() in for loop through id 1 to 10.

Comment: Sorry, but that comment only made it harder for me to understand your issue.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to make it more simpler. I have 10 records in a table called "Integration". There is a filed named "calling frequency" in the table and there are some other fields which store some setting information. DoAction() is a function which does some different task according to the different setting stored in the integration table. now assume we have 10 records in integration table. we need to call DoAction() method at the same time for all integration records, assuming every record has same calling frequency. Is it possible to call any method asynchronously using linux  ?

Answer (score 0):

You must create an php file that includes your class and use it to do all your stuff. After this step you can add you command `php /script/file.php` to your crontab file

Comment: How can I call DoAction() method asynchronously Using PHP. I have a php file. In for loop I am creating object of schedular class and calling DoAction() method. So the code is executing one by one for all integration records.